# Will the doctor operate the patient?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We assume that for a particular illness, a doctor recommends a dangerous surgery if, after a clinical examination and by laboratory tests, he is 80% sure that his patient suffers from it, or, in other case, he recommends further costly examinations. Laboratory tests make a good diagnosis in 99% of cases for non-diabetics and in 70% of cases for diabetics.

After a clinical examination, the doctor is 60% sure that Mr Peter suffers from the disease. Laboratory tests that have a positive result (for the disease) are also done. Will the doctor operate Mr. Peter, believing that Mr. Peter is not diabetic, or will he recommend further tests?

$$$$

Could you give me a hint how we could check that?

Do we consider the haf percentage of the clinical examination and the half percentage of the results of the laboratory tests?

Comment: You update the $60\%$ belief with the result of the test, using conditional probability

Comment: The conditional probability of which events? @Henry

Comment: That the result of the test is positiv given that the patient is non-diabetic? @Henry

Comment: Both.  If, after the clinical examination, the doctor had $600$ patients actually with diabetes and $400$ not, and all $1000$ were then tested, how many of those with diabetes might you expect to test positive?  How many of those without diabetes might you expect to test positive? What proportion of those testing positive might you expect to have diabetes?

Comment: Isn’t it the other way round? The doctor decided that 600 persons were positive and 400 not.  Now compare that probability the lab would get.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the probability to suffer from the disease.  If a person suffers from the disease it will be considered ill with probability $0.7$, so from here $0.7x$ of all will be considered positive.  Additional one percent of the healthy persons will be wrongly considered positive, that is $0.01(1-x)$.  Hence in total
$$0.7x+0.01(1-x)$$ will be considered positive.

This probability must equal the doctor’s estimation for that person to be positive, namely $0.6$. Now solve for $x$.

Comment: Why do we multiply $x$ with $0.7$ and $1-x$ with $1-0.99$ ? Doesn't the doctor believes that Mr. Peter is not diabetic?

Comment: See my edit, please.

Comment: So if, after the tests, the patient Mr. Peter remembers that he is diabetic, then $0.99\cdot x+0.3\cdot (1-x)$ will be considered positive?

Comment: The disease that we check with the test is not the diabetes, right? I got stuck right now.

Comment: In the case where the doctor believes that the patient is not diabetic is the probability not equal to $0.99\cdot x+0.01\cdot (1-x) =0.6$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not really particularly well phrased, as we don't really know what the doctor will do (it'd depend on how costly the test is and how "costly" operating on a healthy patient is). But we definitely can calculate the probability that the patient is sick.

Of course, there are two possibilities that the patient's result is positive, either he is sick and the result is true positive, or he is healthy and the result is a false positive.

You need to find the probability he is **sick and he got a positive result**, and the total probability of getting a positive result (so the previous probability plus the probability that he is **healthy and he got a positive result**). Then, you need to use Bayes' theorem to find the probability that he is sick, **given** that his result was positive.

Comment: Do we not have to calculate the probability $P(\text{ sick } \mid \text{ positive clinical exam. } \cap \text{ positive lab test } \cap \text{ non-diabetic })$ ? Or have I misunderstood it?

Comment: Oh, sorry, to be honest I was in a bit of a rush when I was answering that question, so I missed two details. First of all, you give the minimum probability for operating. And secondly, I assumed diabetes **is** the disease they want to cure by operating. If it's not the case then the answer doesn't change much, **as long as** the $60\%$ is the probability the patient has **diabetes**. Otherwise, we are missing that information.

Comment: Acutally, each time I read that question I understand it differently, you might indeed need to rephrase it :) So the doctor assumes the patient is not diabetic, yes?

Comment: The reason I'm surprised is that if diabetes is the disease than this question is the very common type of exercise for using Bayes' theorem. If it is in fact the case that the test are for a different disease and the doctor just assumes the patient is non-diabetic, then it's equivalent to  assuming the results of the test are correct with $99%$ probability, in which case - yes, the doctor would operate. But are you sure that's the actual task here?